# Registry Setting - Windows lock screen grace period

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I understand that there's a [registry setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/221784/screen-saver-grace-period-bypasses-password-protection) for configuring a period of time after the screen saver has activated during which the user can provide input (e.g. mouse movement) and not have to log-in again before using the computer.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\ScreenSaverGracePeriod
```

I don't use a screen-saver, and thus this setting doesn't apply.

Is there such a configuration setting for allowing a grace-period after the computer logs the user out, during which time it's not necessary to re-authenticate?

Comment: `Is there such a configuration setting for allowing a grace-period after the computer logs the user out, during which time it's not necessary to re-authenticate?` - I've never heard of such a setting, but imagine what a security risk that would be.

Comment: @joeqwerty An activity timeout that results in a screensaver (possibly with a password) or to the login screen is still a timeout. The 'grace' period of a few seconds (default is 5sec for the screen saver) even compared to a conservative lockout period of say 5min, really isn't a security risk.

Comment: In the standard configuration, such functionality would not be very useful; you might occasionally log out and immediately change your mind, but probably not often enough to matter.  I'm guessing your computer is configured to log you out automatically after some idle timeout, and the problem is that you don't know when it is about to happen so can't cancel it.  I suggest that you try configuring a screensaver to kick in one minute earlier than the automatic logout, so that you can use the screensaver grace period setting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no lock-out grace period when using auto-lockout without the screen saver.

The work-around it to use the screen-saver, set the grace period for the screen-saver (see the question's registry key reference), and then ensure "On resume, display logon screen" is checked in Screen Saver Settings.

[image: Screen Saver Settings]